# Open native maps from the windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, contacts, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to open the native maps on a button click on windows phone 8.1 ?

I am looking for an API which imitates the native contact store feature where if you click on a map on the address of a contact, the native maps should open up.

Comment: Open within your app, or open the maps app separately?

Comment: Separately. Not in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to use the ms-drive-to or ms-walk-to Uri scheme! When you use those, the phone itself will launch HERE drive if it is present, otherwise Bing maps!

Get the needed example code and usage on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can open either Bing Maps (on all phones) or HERE Maps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394026%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/change-history/archived-content/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/here-launchers-api-reference.html